# Typescript definition for a class within a namespace

Tags: typescript

how can I create a typescript definition file "*.d.ts" for a class inside a namespace with constructor arguments (existing javascript library). I tried several combinations of a module with a nested interface, but nothing worked so far.

Example:

```
var instance = new Namespace.TargetClass(arg1, arg2);
instance.someFunc(arg3);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare module Namespace {
    class TargetClass {
        constructor(arg1: string, arg2: number);
        someFunc(arg3: any): void;
    }   
}
```